# Twig > for looping on objects -> only one result

Tags: templating

Sorry per advance for my english :/

I am trying to construct an twig array in a .twig file like this :

```
{% set allergenesArray = [] %}
    {% for allergne in recipe.allergenes %}
      {% set allergenesArray = allergenesArray|merge({
        allergne
      }) %}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ dump(allergenesArray) }}
```

The result of the dump is [image: Dump of the array].

The code works fine but in fact, I should have **2** objects : I think the first one is erased but I really don't why...

If anyone has an idea...

Thanks per advance and good evening

Answer (score 2):

*Note: I have used the English singular **allergen** and plural **allergens** in my examples here—it’s just easier for me to proofread in my native language!*

I believe what is happening is that your code is repeatedly merging an associative array on top of an associative array, overwriting the same `allergen` key.

That said,`recipe.allergens` is probably already an array—can you just use it as-is? It would be helpful to know what kind of field you're working with.

To rebuild the array, you would need append to `allergensArray`, like this:

```
{% set allergensArray = [] %}

{% for allergen in recipe.allergens %}
  {# Create a single-element array to merge: #}
  {% set allergensArray = allergensArray|merge([allergen]) %}
{% endfor %}

{{ dump(allergensArray) }}
```

The core issue (I think) is that the curly braces inside your `merge()` filter (`merge({ allergen })`) is creating an object like this…

```
{
  allergen: (Allergen model 1)
}
```

…which is then getting merged with another object like this, the second time around…

```
{
  allergen: (Allergen model 2)
}
```

…and squashing the `allergen` key from the first loop.

---

Aside: I don't recognize `App\Enti…` as a Craft namespace—is this indeed a Craft application?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for your response which is very clear :

Yes, the `recipe.allergens` is an array which contains `alergene` types with an `id` and a `name` properties.

-> In DB : `Allergen(id, name)`.

I tried your solution but it doesn't work. I don't think it is the good way to do...

```
{% set allergensArray = [] %}
    {% for allergen in recipe.allergenes %}
      {% set singleElement = {'id' : allergen.id, 'name' : allergen.name} %}
      {% set allergensArray = allergensArray|merge({singleElement}) %}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ dump(allergensArray) }}
```

The result is :
[image: Result]

I am googling for a solution but not found for the moment.

Thank you again

Comment: Inside your merge, you need to wrap the singleElement with square bracket instead curly bracket, so it would allergensArray|merge([singleElement])